# MySQL: SQL Returning Just Three Results of a Field

Tags: mysql, sql

The query below produces working results but I would like to return just the first 3 rows for each team:

```
mysql> select * from plain_result;
+-----------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------+---------+------------+----------------+
| fixtureid | fixturedate                | team           | opponent       | result | mstatus | team_score | opponent_score |
+-----------+----------------------------+----------------+----------------+--------+---------+------------+----------------+
|    364322 | 2016-10-02 15:30:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Burnley        | W      | A       |          1 |              0 |
|    364310 | 2016-09-24 16:30:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Chelsea        | W      | H       |          3 |              0 |
|    364295 | 2016-09-17 14:00:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Hull           | W      | A       |          4 |              1 |
|    364288 | 2016-09-10 14:00:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Southampton    | W      | H       |          2 |              1 |
|    364277 | 2016-08-27 14:00:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Watford        | W      | A       |          3 |              1 |
|    364270 | 2016-08-20 16:30:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Leicester      | D      | A       |          0 |              0 |
|    364261 | 2016-08-14 15:00:00.000000 | Arsenal        | Liverpool      | L      | H       |          3 |              4 |
|    364315 | 2016-10-01 14:00:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | Watford        | D      | A       |          2 |              2 |
|    364307 | 2016-09-24 14:00:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | Everton        | W      | H       |          1 |              0 |
|    364297 | 2016-09-17 14:00:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | Man City       | L      | A       |          0 |              4 |
|    364286 | 2016-09-10 14:00:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | West Brom      | W      | H       |          1 |              0 |
|    364276 | 2016-08-27 14:00:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | Crystal Palace | D      | A       |          1 |              1 |
|    364272 | 2016-08-21 15:00:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | West Ham       | L      | A       |          0 |              1 |
|    364260 | 2016-08-14 12:30:00.000000 | Bournemouth    | Man United     | L      | H       |          1 |              3 |
|    364322 | 2016-10-02 15:30:00.000000 | Burnley        | Arsenal        | L      | H       |          0 |              1 |
|    364312 | 2016-09-26 19:00:00.000000 | Burnley        | Watford        | W      | H       |          2 |              0 |
|    364296 | 2016-09-17 14:00:00.000000 | Burnley        | Leicester      | L      | A       |          0 |              3 |
|    364287 | 2016-09-10 14:00:00.000000 | Burnley        | Hull           | D      | H       |          1 |              1 |
|    364275 | 2016-08-27 14:00:00.000000 | Burnley        | Chelsea        | L      | A       |          0 |              3 |
|    364266 | 2016-08-20 14:00:00.000000 | Burnley        | Liverpool      | W      | H       |          2 |              0 |
|    364257 | 2016-08-13 14:00:00.000000 | Burnley        | Swansea        | L      | H       |          0 |              1 |
```

**Please note the plain_result is based on a view and not a table.**

Many thanks, Alan.

Comment: Which three do you want to return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, the best way to do this in MySQL is to use variables:

```
select pr.*
from (select pr.*,
             (@rn := if(@t = team, @rn + 1,
                        if(@t := team, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as seqnum
      from plain_result pr cross join
           (select @rn := 0, @t := '') params
      order by team, ??
     ) pr
where seqnum <= 3;
```

The `??` is for the column that defines which three you want.  In all likelihood, it is probably `fixturedate asc` or `fixturedate desc`.

Comment: I get the following error: "Table 'dwad.plain_results' doesn't exist".  This is because it is based on a view, my apologies.   I will add it to the question.

Comment: After a few more searches on google it seemed it should not matter whether it was a view or not.  I then had a browse through your code and noticed plain_result had been pluralised to plain_results.  I removed the s and it worked perfectly.  Thank you.